# Injecting database configuration values that might change per request in Simple Injector using ResolveUnregisteredType event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a SettingRegistration method like below.

```
static void SettingRegistration(this ContainerOptions options)
{
    options.Container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (sender, e) =>
    {
        //The type implemented ISetting interface
        if (e.UnregisteredServiceType.GetInterface("ISetting")!=null)
        {
            var settingInstance = (ISetting)Activator.CreateInstance(e.UnregisteredServiceType);
            var settingService = ((Container) sender).GetInstance<ISettingService>();
            var s = settingService.GetSetting(settingInstance);

            // Register the instance as singleton.
            e.Register(() => s);
        }
    };
}
```

The methot that register class with Singleton Lifestyle.

My question is: How to register with Scoped Lifestyle in this context.

**UPDATE**

I have got application setting classes.

```
public class StoreSetting:ISetting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CartSetting:ISetting
{
    public string CartType { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, `ISetting` interface is represented these setting classes.

```
public interface ISetting
{        
}
```

On the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event, I need to populate them from database on every request. Same application was made at nopCommerce setting infrastructure. I am confused. Do you give me a code snippet?

Comment: Why do you want to load configuration settings with a scoped lifestyle? Why are you expecting them to change during the lifetime of your application? You also might want to give a little background information on what you are trying to achieve, since loading configuration settings like this might not be the best way to do this.

Comment: Because when some of one configuration setting is changed by the admin, I expect to reload them.

Comment: How are those configuration settings stored? Normal configuration settings can only be reloaded when the application is restarted.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: Thank you @Steven. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `UnregisteredTypeEventArgs.Register` overload that accepts a `Registration` instance. You can create it using `Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateRegistration(Type, Func<object>, Container)`.

From your update, it becomes more clear what you are trying to achieve. You are loading configuration settings from the database per request. Your configuration settings are in your case runtime data (since it changes per request). As described [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) however, Injecting runtime data into components is an anti-pattern.

So instead of using the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event to hook up these values, my advise is to change your design so that runtime configuration values are loaded after the object graph has been built. You can do this by defining an interface for this:

```
public interface ISettingProvider<TSetting> where TSetting : ISetting
{
    TSetting Value { get; }
}
```

The use of this provider abstraction allows to delay the loading of these configuration values after the object graph has been built. A generic implementation can be defined as follows:

```
public class SettingProvider<TSetting> : ISettingProvider<TSetting>
    where TSetting : ISetting, new()
{
    private readonly ISettingService service;

    public SettingProvider(ISettingService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public TSetting Value => this.service.GetSetting(new TSetting());
}
```

This generic class can be registered as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(ISettingProvider<>), typeof(SettingProvider<>));
```

This way you can inject the proper `ISettingProvider<TSetting>` into a consumer:

```
public class ProcessCartHandler
{
    private readonly ISettingProvider<CartSetting> cartSettingProvider;

    public ProcessCartHandler(ISettingProvider<CartSetting> cartSettingProvider) {
        this.cartSettingProvider = cartSettingProvider;
    }

    public void Handle(ProcessCartHandler command) {
        // Read configuration value
        string cartType = cartSettingProvider.Value.CartType;
        // Use it.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used:

Container config:

```
private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IDataContextAsync, AppContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<IRepositoryAsync<Setting>, Repository<Setting>>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<ISettingService, SettingService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    container.Register(typeof(ISettingProvider<>), typeof(SettingProvider<>));
    //container.Options.SettingRegistration();
}
```

SettingProvider

```
public interface ISettingProvider<TSetting> where TSetting : ISetting
{
    TSetting Value { get; }
}


public class SettingProvider<TSetting> : ISettingProvider<TSetting> 
    where TSetting : ISetting, new()
{
    private readonly ISettingService service;
    public SettingProvider(ISettingService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public TSetting Value => this.service.LoadSetting<TSetting>();

}
```

SettingServices

```
public interface ISettingService : IService<Setting>
{
    T LoadSetting<T>() where T : ISetting, new();
    ISetting LoadSettingOLD(object setting);
    void SetSetting(ISetting setting);
}

public class SettingService : Service<Setting>, ISettingService {
    private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Setting> _repository;

    public SettingService(IRepositoryAsync<Setting> repository) : base(repository) {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public T LoadSetting<T>() where T : ISetting, new() {
        var setting = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        var settingName = setting.GetType().Name;
        var properties = setting.GetType().GetProperties();
        var ayars = GetAllSettingsCached()
            .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(settingName)).ToList();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var settingPropertyName = settingName + "." + propertyInfo.Name;
            var q = ayars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == settingPropertyName);
            if (q != null)
            {
                propertyInfo.SetValue(setting, 
                    Convert.ChangeType(q.Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }
        return setting;
    }
}
```